# How to include the JSON Schema definition of a JSONField inside the OpenAPI schema generated by drf-spectacular?

Tags: python, django, openapi, jsonschema, drf-spectacular

By default, when using `drf-spectacular` to generate the OpenAPI schema, the JSONField will be typed as `object` or `array`. However, I have a JSON Field which is validated against a JSON Schema and I'd like this JSON Schema to be included on the OpenAPI schema.

I couldn't find this specific scenario described on the docs of `drf-spectacular`, but however, I tried modifying it using `@extend_schema` but with no success.

The model looks like this:

```py
Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    data = models.JSONField("Car Data", validators=[JSONSchemaValidator(limit_value=my_schema)])
```

On the generated OpenAPI schema, this is represented as:

```yaml
data:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: {}
    nullable: true
    title: Car Data
```

I'm not including a sample on how it should look because I'm seeking answers where this is possible in some pre-defined way.